# How can I set the correct order of files to be concatenated with gulp-bundle-assets

Tags: gulp

I use **gulp-bundle-assets** for processing my static resources. I have the next configuration in my **bundle.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
bundle: {
    ...
    vendor: {
        scripts: [
            './bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            './bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
            './bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js',
            './bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
            './bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js'
        ]
        options: {
            uglify: false,
            order: {
                scripts: [
                    'angular.js',
                    '*.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
...
};
```

Thus, the first script to be concatenated must be angular.js, but "options.order" doesn't work correct - the first concatenated file in the final script is angular-animate.js. So, my question is how to achieve the correct order?

Comment: use gulp-wiredep to get correct depenedency order.. and btw from the config that you specified seems like you are using grunt and not gulp

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [gulp-bundle-assets](https://github.com/dowjones/gulp-bundle-assets). The problem is with your glob syntax. Under the covers, gulp-bundle-assets uses [gulp-order](https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order), which itself uses [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch). The docs for each give lots of examples but for your particular use-case, this minimatch example shows your problem:

```
var minimatch = require("minimatch")
minimatch("./bower_components/angular/angular.js", "angular.js") // false
minimatch("./bower_components/angular/angular.js", "./**/angular.js") // true
```

Unfortunately the `./` at the beginning is throwing off minimatch. The following should fix your problem:

```
options: {
  order: {
    scripts: [
      './**/angular.js',
      './**/*.js'
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.